# Filtering through date range not working in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, count

I am trying to count the total orders made by customers in the last week. I have used ordered_date__range in my view but my API is showing count as zero. I am not sure what is the issue here because I know there are orders made in my db.

My view:

```
class DashboardView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        count_1 = Order.objects.filter(order_items__item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk']).count()
        ......................

        startdate = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)
        enddate = startdate - timedelta(days=30)

        count_8 = Order.objects.filter(order_items__item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk'],ordered_date__range=[startdate, enddate]).count()
        

        return Response(
            {'active_users_now': count_2,
             'total_customers': count_9,
                'total_orders': count_1,
             'total_categories': count_3,
             'total_subcategories' : count_6,
             'total_products_available': count_4,
             'total_prodcuts_sold': count_5,
             'total_earnings': count_7,
              'total_orders_of_the_week': count_8,
             },
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here If I call the above api, my count is showing zero. I just tried adding 2 or 3 orders, but still getting zero counts.

I tried removing this part `order_items__item__merchant=self.kwargs['pk'],` as well, but its the same result of zero. COunt_1 is totally working.

**I am just trying to capture of orders made by customers of a particular merchant within the last week.**

My model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
   
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    #order_items = models.ManyToManyField('OrderItem',blank=True, null=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Provide all other models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date range looks wrong because your `enddate` is previous to `startdate`:

```py
startdate = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)
enddate = startdate - timedelta(days=30)
```

Also, you are talking about `a week` and you figure up 30 days.

I guess it should be:

```py
startdate = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=8)
enddate = startdate + timedelta(days=7)
```

Comment: Okay thanks dani, it worked .But I am getting this warning. Can you check my code again??

Comment: hi @Django-Rocks, I guess your original question has been answered. Don't mix questions in a post, just create a new post or search for your new issue in posted questions. Regards.